# Angular CLI compile error; Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

This is my first angular project, and I was trucking right along, using the built in server, and occasionally doing a build to push to a server - now I'm trying a --prod build ...and Im getting compile errors.

Thu a buch of reading I've managed to solve most of them and I understand the AOT needs, however this one error has me baffled

I use this code repeatedly thru the app to start my forms,

```
<form novalidate="novalidate"
    autocomplete="off"
    [formGroup]="form"
    (submit)="form.valid && submitForm()" >
```

but on a few of these templates I am getting

```
x.component.html(6,3): : Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

where line 6 is: (submit)="form.valid && submitForm()" >

======== 
    NOTE: I have reduced the code to a bare bones

```
and included it here, so you see EXACTLY what is there...

no extrapolating or generalizing.

Builds fine in dev mode
```

## cli v(1.6.0)

I still get the same error - user-form.component.html(6,4): Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

So I thought I'd give the full component and template.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, NgForm, NgControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms/src/model';
import { ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/validators';

import { get } from 'lodash';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
})

export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitAttempted = false;

    constructor(
    ) { }

    get formDisabled () {
        return this.loading === true;
    }

    get xStatus () {
        const field = this.form.get('x');
        if (!field.touched) {
            return '';
        }
        if (field.errors && field.errors.required) {
            return 'This field is required';
        }
    }


    get formModel () {
        return {
            x: this.form.get('x').value
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            x: new FormControl(
                {
                    value: 'x',
                    disabled: this.formDisabled,
                },
                [
                    Validators.required
                ]
            )
        })
    }

    resetForm () {
        this.form.get('x').markAsUntouched();
        this.submitAttempted = false;
    }

    submitForm(form: NgForm) {
        console.log( this.form );
    }

    showError (fieldName: string) {
        const field = this.form.get(fieldName);
        return field.invalid && (field.touched || this.submitAttempted);
    }

}
```

**template.ts** (user-form.component.html)

```
<form 
    novalidate="novalidate"
    autocomplete="off"
    [formGroup]="form"
    (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" >

    <label class="input" [class.state-error]="showError('x')">
        <input type="text" name="x" placeholder="x" formControlName="x" />
        <div *ngIf="xStatus" [innerHTML]="xStatus | safeHtml"></div>
    </label>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitAttempted = true">
        <i *ngIf="loading" class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i>
        {{ loading ? 'Saving' : 'Add x' }}
    </button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because in your form class, submitForm expects the form as an argument, but in the template you aren't passing a form.

Opinionated solution: Don't do that.  Just use submitForm() to trigger validation on your form.  There's no reason to be handing the form instance back to itself.

Comment: Are you saying...submitForm(form: NgForm) { } should be submitForm() {} ?

Comment: Yes. The code that is executing is the form controller which created the form instance. There is no need to pass the form instance back to the controller since it is already bound.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead `(submit)="submitForm()"`. You can check `form.valid` in the `submitForm` function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your component code

```
submitForm(form: NgForm) { }
```

The argument passed is not required as such because you have already linked the form with component and template. This requires you to pass the argument also in your template.But removing it from the component will work 100%

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
<form #f="ngForm" id="someForm" name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && buyTicket(ticket)" novalidate>
```

was produced error

```
ERROR in src\app\event\event.component.html(23,54): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

it means that in `.ts` file must be buggy function without an argument - `buyTicket()`. 
I mean not only form instance can produce this error, but it can be also any buggy function.

Answer (score -1):

```
To Submit a form you need to use ngSubmit on the form, and to enable/disable the submit button in the form, we can check like this: form.valid and bind this to the button disabled attribute.

Something like this:
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
<button type="submit" [disabled]='!form.valid'>Submit</button>
</form>
```